# A conflict exists with definition leftIdle1 in namespace internal

Tags: actionscript-3, stage, instances

I'm scripting a game with Actionscript 3.0 in Flash Professional CS5.5, but I get an error.

```
Scene 1, Layer 'as2', Frame 153, Line 4 1151: A conflict exists with definition leftIdle1 in namespace internal.
```

(I get these with the other Variables too.)

Now it's a platform game, and I am going to put cutscenes throughout in the game and I need to switch from frames and put the code in another frame. But it gives that error, I turned off the 'Automatic Declare stage instances' function, now I checked this website and Googled it, people get it with their Movieclips, I get it with my variables.

This is my script:

```
var leftKeyDown1:Boolean = false;
var rightKeyDown1:Boolean = false;
var spaceKeyDown1:Boolean = false;
var leftIdle1:Boolean = false;
var rightIdle1:Boolean = true;
var mainSpeed1:Number = 4;


player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveChar);
function moveChar(event:Event)
{

    if (leftKeyDown1)
    {
        player.x -=  mainSpeed1;
        leftIdle1 = true;
        rightIdle1 = false;
        player.gotoAndStop("walk_left");
    }
    if (rightKeyDown1)
    {
        player.x +=  mainSpeed1;
        rightIdle1 = true;
        leftIdle1 = false;
        player.gotoAndStop("walk_right");
    }

    if (rightIdle1 && !rightKeyDown1 && !leftKeyDown1)
    {
        player.gotoAndStop("idle_right");
    }
    else if (leftIdle1 && !rightKeyDown1 && !leftKeyDown1)
    {
        player.gotoAndStop("idle_left");
    }

    if (collide.hitTestObject(player))
    {
        player.x = player.x + mainSpeed1;
    }

    if (trigger1.hitTestObject(player))
    {
        son1.gotoAndStop("walkRight");
        trigger1.gotoAndStop(2);
        son1.x +=  2;
    }
    if (trigger2.hitTestObject(player))
    {
        gotoAndPlay(4);
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, checkKeysDown);
function checkKeysDown(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if (event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 65)
    {
        leftKeyDown1 = true;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 68)
    {
        rightKeyDown1 = true;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 32)
    {
        spaceKeyDown1 = true;
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkKeysU1);
function checkKeysUp(event:KeyboardEvent)
{

    if (event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 65)
    {
        leftKeyDown1 = false;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 32)
    {
        spaceKeyDown1 = false;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 68)
    {
        rightKeyDown1 = false;
    }

}
```

It's probably coded in a weird way, but whatever.
I have no idea what to do at this point.
Help would be really appreciated.

EDIT:

Oh I got another error too. It's with Duplicate function, and I can't seem to fix it but to rename those, and it will take a long time to rename them every-time. So if someone has something for that, thanks!

Comment: you have duplicated definitions, eg: "var leftIdle1:Boolean" multiple times - remove the duplicates

Comment: Oh, so it just creates those variables throughout the whole file? So it can be used later but without having to declare it again? Thanks!

Now, how does this work with the Duplicate Function? I have the same events on another frame too.

Comment: yep - just put all definitions on first frame. Same thing with functions - remove duplicates (or rename them if easier)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have duplicated definitions.

For example:

```
var leftIdle1:Boolean
```

exists multiple times - remove the duplicates